# How do I 301 redirect old permalinks to new permalink

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I am changing my permalinks structure and need help redirecting old links using this structure..................

```
www.sitename.com/stores/storename
```

To new:

```
www.sitename.com/coupon-codes/storename
```

I am using wordpress, tried using this rewrite rule but doesn't work....

```
Redirect permanent stores/storename  http://www.sitename.com/coupon-codes/storename
```

Answer (score 0):

In your htaccess file, you do this.

```
redirect 301 /stores/storename http://www.sitename.com/coupon-codes/storename
redirect 301 /stores/storename1 http://www.sitename.com/coupon-codes/storename1
redirect 301 /stores/storename2 http://www.sitename.com/coupon-codes/storename2
redirect 301 /stores/storename3 http://www.sitename.com/coupon-codes/storename3
```